# Parse command arp -a for only ip

Tags: text-processing, awk, arp, ip-address

I need to parse the command `arp -a` to get only the ip of the device. Right now I have

`arp -a | awk '{print $2}' | head -1`

However this gives me

`(192.168.1.71)`

and I must remove the `( )` from the output. How can this be done?

Comment: welcome to U&L, what do you meant by **get the only ip of the device** ? on most unix/linux system `arp -a` will give a random list of recently used IPs and MACs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the characters `()` as field separators instead of whitespace:

```
arp -a | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

using `cut` :

```
arp -a | awk '{print $2}' | head -1 | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1
```

Updating the answer as suggested in the comment:

`cut` explanation:

`-d` - acts as delimiter and splits the string on first occurrence of `(`

`-f` - selects the specified field. Here selects the 2nd part which would be `x.x.x.x)`

We give this output as input to next `cut` using `|`

`cut -d ")" -f 1` - This again splits the input on `)` and we select the first part i.e. Just the IP address.

Comment: It's considered a good practise to explain a command so future users can learn something and adapt it to their needs.

Comment: @Philippos - Sure will keep in mind. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tr` is good at things like deleting unwanted characters:

```
$ tr -d '()' <<< '(192.168.1.1)'
192.168.1.1
```

So all told, it would be:

```
arp -a | awk '{print $2}' | head -1 | tr -d '()'
```